# EMR Output to S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, emr

I am running Python script on EMR On-Demand server (dont have named EMR cluster). It works fine giving Input & Output as my local system. I want to use S3 bucket as my Input & output. See my command below.
It takes input from S3 bucket fine. But displaying output only to my local system, not to S3. Could you please help me?

```
$ python WordFrequency.py -r emr --region us-east-1 s3://mybucket/Input/Book.txt s3://mybucket/Output
```

Regards
Mohan

Comment: please share the code snippet for WordFrequency.py

Answer (score 0):

Just putting this here in case anyone else needs it. There's two things that I see wrong with the query:

1. The url should be 's3a', not 's3', as explained [here](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.3/bk_cloud-data-access/content/s3a-uri.html)
2. When adding to folders in a bucket the folder address needs to be closed off. 's3://mybucket/Output' needs to be 's3a://mybucket/Output/'

A third thing that could be wrong is that your emr/client user doesn't have permissions to access the bucket in the first place. Make sure that the IAM settings for the EMR/client user give that user access to S3 puts and reads and the bucket you are writing to has the correct permissions.